# Is it possible to catch a "load denied by x-frame option" error in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, iframe, cross-domain

I am facing several difficulties while trying to load an Iframe in an AngularJS view, and I have the following error :

```
Load denied by X-Frame-Options: http://www.example.com does not permit cross-origin framing.
```

When facing this type of error, which happens with some links, I would like to hide the Iframe, so I would need to catch this error. You can find below the HTML and JS code I am using.

HTML :

```
<iframe id="contentIframe" ng-src="{{trustSrc()}}" frameborder="0" fullscreen></iframe>
```

Controller :

```
$scope.trustSrc = function () {
  return $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(ContentService.getCurrentContent().url);
};
```

I went through several questions on StackOverflow but I could not manage to find the answer. **Is there a way to catch the following error in AngularJS ?**

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: No.

The DOM API does not allow binding events to the `contentWindow` object or the `contentDocument` object if that iframe is loading another website. In fact, there is almost no inspection you can do on the state of the iframe if the URL is cross domain and your domain is not explicitly whitelisted by that domain.

Therefore it would not be possible to do it via AngularJs.